# Bash differences between { } and ( )?

Tags: bash

What's the difference bewteen `( )` and `{ }` when coding in Bash ? 
When should I use one or the other ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Braces do not start a subshell; parentheses do.

```
$ x=3
$ { x=4; }; echo "$x"
4
$ ( x=5 ); echo "$x"
4
```

Usually, unless you specifically need to localize a parameter assignment, you can use `{}`.